# Linearly convert color space of RGB image in Octave

Tags: octave, color-space

I have a 3x3 matrix used to linearly transform RGB colors. How can I convert the color space of an RGB image using that matrix? Should I loop through all the pixels and convert them one by one or does a faster way exist?

Comment: Please tag *either* Octave *or* MATLAB, unless your issue concerns specifically both languages. There may be solutions permissible in one language, which are nog in the other. See the tag-excerpts of both [tag:octave] and [tag:matlab] please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your 3x3 matrix `M` is supposed to be multiplied with your pixel value `p` as follows:

```
new_p = M * p;
```

(with `p` a column vector), then you can transform your `n`x`m`x3 image matrix as follows:

```
m = 1920;
n = 1080; 
img = rand(n, m, 3);
tmp = reshape(img, [], 3); % no copy made
tmp = tmp * M.';
new_img = reshape(tmp, n, m, 3);
```

Note that here we transformed `M * p` into `p.' * M.'`, so that we don't need to transpose the image, which would require copying all its data to a new array. Transposing `M` is a lot cheaper than transposing `tmp`.

You can do the above in a single line, avoiding the need for the `tmp` array:

```
new_img = reshape(reshape(img, [], 3) * M.', n, m, 3);
```

Comment: Hijacking this comment thread just to say I enjoyed browsing through your blog, Cris. Maybe I should finally start mine ...

Comment: @Tasos: Thank you! And yes, you should start a blog. I'm sure you have a lot to share.